# Python: How to put multiple .txt files into their own libraries, respectively.

Tags: python, libraries

Im trying to iterate through 3 text files, and count each unique word in them- and making a library of those unique words for each file, then adding those libraries (which i have made into lists) together. For example, 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', and 'file3.txt' will all have their own libraries.

```
def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

def memes():

for filename in ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt']:
    txt = open(filename, 'r').read()
    txt = text.lower()
    for char in '!""#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\" ':
        txt = text.replace(char, ' ')
    words = txt.split()

    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w,0) + 1

    itms = list(counts.itms())
    itms.sort()
    itms.sort(key = byFreq, reverse=True)
    for i in range(50):
        word, count = items[i]
        print ("{0:<15}{1:>5}".format(word, count))
```

This is what i have at this point. It iterates through all the lists correctly, but only returns me a list of unique words for each first iteration.

```
 the            14352
 of              6617
 and             6355
 a               4644
 to              4605
```

Because 'file1.txt' has 'the' in it 14352 times, it returns that number and discards the other instances of 'the' in the other files. It does this for the other words as well, until it comes across another unique word in one of the other files that hasn't been mentioned before.

What i'm trying to get it to do is add all of the instances of 'the',as well as all the words, in all of the files. I'm stuck at this point above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code example appears to be incomplete and incorrectly formatted (indentation of the `memes` function). For example, where is `counts` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english, I don't speak well.

I solved the exercise it this way:

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter()

for filename in ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']:
    txt = open(filename, 'r').read()
    txt = txt.lower()
    for char in '!""#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\" ':
        txt = txt.replace(char, ' ')
    words = txt.split()
    for word in words:
        counter[word] += 1

for word, count in counter.most_common(5): #print 5 most common words
    print("{0:<15}{1:>5}".format(word, count))
```

good bye